# Shift facet label to the left so that y-axis has some more space

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to give my y axis labels a room to breath, by shifting the my facet lables a bit to the left. I am not sure how best to do this on ggplot. Does anyone have a suggestion on how best to do this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme setting you might be looking for is `strip.switch.pad.grid`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy, class)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(year ~ ., switch = "y") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
p
```

[image]

```r
p + theme(strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `+ theme(strip.placement = "outside")` in your code. It should work.

Comment: I already have that as part of my code. :/

Comment: Could you then please send it and a sample of your data? It's quite hard to help without knowing what you have already try :)